# "As a child" vs. "When I was a child"

Tags: expressions

> 1. ***As a child***, I was allowed to watch as much television on Saturday and Sunday mornings as I pleased.
> 2. ***When I was a child***, I was allowed to watch as much television on Saturday and Sunday mornings as I pleased.

Is really "As a child" a proper way to say "When I was a child" in the case above?

As far as I understand, it seems to me that these two expressions are not entirely interchangeable.

Can anybody explain?

Comment: If you add "I" to the begining of the first sentence -  "As I was a child" , they both would mean pretty much the same , in either case, I woud avoid to use two forms of "as"(conjunction and adverb)  in the same sentence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*As a child* will bear this interpretation; but it has other senses.  For instance:

> **As a child, I was not allowed into the bar.** ... Here, *as a child* probably means not *when I was a child* but ***because** I was a child*.
>
> **As a child, she supported the laws against internet bullying; as a citizen, she regretted the possible infringement on free speech.** ... Here, *as a child* means *in her role as a child* (and therefore a potential victim of internet bullying), as opposed to *in her role as a citizen* (and therefore a potential victim of oppression).
>
> **As a child do I follow the precepts of my Master.** ... Here, *as a child* probably means *in the manner of a child*

So you have to be more careful when using *as X* in a temporal sense, lest one of these other senses interfere with your readers' understanding. On the other hand, the context will usually make your sense clear, so you don't have to be *too* careful.

Comment: ***As a** native speaker*, I have to say you've summarised three other common senses very succinctly (which *as a* rule is the case with your answers! :)

Answer (score 6):

While [StoneyB covers meanings of *as a child*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3762/133) that differ from the meaning shared with *when I was a child*, the alternate use of *when I was a child* is not clearly addressed.

**When I was a child** *can* be used to describe the speaker **as a child**, but it can also be used to refer to a particular time.

> **When I was a child**, George Washington was the President of the U.S.

Substituting *as a child* would mean that George Washington was President during his childhood.

Answer (score 3):

The first one sounds like you're comparing your present condition against the past; while second one is like you are just remembering something from your childhood.

---

<sub>Probably not a descriptive answer</sub>